# php explode product array throwing up errors

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, explode

I have set up an 'orders' page that should be pretty straight-forward, requiring a for each loop to generate past orders from the DB.  Within each loop, there needs to be an explode to separate each item(,), then another explode to pull the details out of each item(-). I was wondering if anyone could tell me why I'm getting the error message "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1" at the end of each iteration of my foreach loop?  It's particularly confusing for me because the code still works, which I don't think it should if the error was true.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE store='$user'";  
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$arrOrders = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    array_push($arrOrders, $row);
}
?>

<table width="85%" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5">
    <?php if (count($arrOrders) > 0) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($arrOrders as $key => $value) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="font-weight: bold">
                ID #<?=$value['id']?>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="font-weight: bold">
                Status: <?=$value['status']?>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="font-weight: bold">
                Order #<?=$value['order_ref']?>
            </td>
            <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-weight: bold">
                <?php
                $tmpProds = explode(',', $value['products']);
                foreach ($tmpProds as $key2 => $value2) {
                        $tmpProdInfo = explode('-', $value2);

                $sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM products_full WHERE id = ' . $tmpProdInfo[0];
                $res2 = mysql_query($sql2);

                if (mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0) { // THIS IS THE ROW THAT THE ERROR MESSAGE POINTS TO
                echo $tmpProdInfo[1] + $tmpProdInfo[2] . ' x <a href="item_details.php?id=' . mysql_result($res2, 0, 'id') . '">' . mysql_result($res2, 0, 'alpha_code') . ' (' . trim(mysql_result($res2, 0, 'description')) . ')</a><br /><br />';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" colspan="5" align="center">
                <hr style="width: 100%" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="center">
            There are currently no complete orders.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </table>
```

Thanks in advance, I think I've included everything that is relative but if anything else is needed please let me know.

Joe

Comment: It looks as if your query `$sql2` is failing and therefore an invalid result resource is being passed to `mysql_num_rows()`

Comment: Thank you @deifwud, and as it's happening at the end of each loop would it make sense that it is because it is being fed an empty portion of an array?  The array before any explosion is being separated by commas(e.g 3-3-3,4-4-4,) but it also ends in a comma so would my first explosion create an empty array as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql2 = 'SELECT * FROM products_full WHERE id = '.$tmpProdInfo[1].'';
if (count($res2) > 0)
```

Also, be aware when you want to use MySQL_num_rows you should include the connection. see the manual:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I do have the mysql connection open in an include elsewhere on the page, does it still require connection using the 'link' method from the manual?

Comment: I've tried using the count method, which has the same result as removing the if statement entirely, which is that is throws up the same error message but 3 times.

Comment: maybe your explode method gives you a null value at `$tmpProdInfo[0]` try to change it like this `$tmpProdInfo[1]` and then use `count` or `mysql_num_rows`.